# MongoDB - How to get result from nested document without document structure

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a document with the following structure:

```
{
    "aaa": {
        "bbb":{
            "ccc":123
            "ddd":456
        }
    }
}
```

When querying, I use `db.mycoll.find({},{"aaa.bbb.ccc": 1})` to get only the number `123`, but MongoDB will return the result with the full structure as

```
{
    "aaa": {
        "bbb":{
            "ccc":123
        }
    }
}
```

How to avoid MongoDB from returning the full structure and only return the inner value?

Answer (score 1):

You can map a function ::

Try like this :

```
db.mycoll.find({},{"aaa.bbb.ccc":1}).map( function(u) { return u.aaa.bbb.ccc;})
```

**Result ::** [ 123 ]

Answer (score 0):

A way by using aggregation can be something like this:

```
db.mycoll.aggregate(
    [
        {
            $project: {
                _id: "$aaa.bbb.ccc"
            }
        },
    ]
);
```

Result will be:

```
{ 
    "value" : 123.0
}
```